# solr fuzzy vs wildcard vs stemmer

Tags: solr, lucene

I have couple of questions here.

I want to search a term `jumps`

With Fuzzy search, I can do `jump~`
With wild card search, I can do `jump*`
With stemmer I can do, `jump`

My understanding is that, fuzzy search gives `pump`. Wildcard search gives `jumping` as well. Stemmer gives "jumper" also.

I totally agree with the results.

1. What is the performance of thes three?

   - Wild card is not recommended if it is at the beginning of the term - my understanding as it has to match with all the tokens in the index - But in this case, it would be all the tokens which starts jump
   - Fuzzy search gives me unpredicted results - It has to do something kind of spellcheck I assume.
   - Stemmer suits only particular scenarios like it can;t match pumps.
2. How should I use these things which can give more relevant results?

I probably more confused about all these because of [this section](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-FuzzySearches). Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

1. Wildcard queries are (generally) not analysed (i.e. they're not tokenized or run through filters), meaning that anything that depend on filters doing their processing of the input/output tokens will give weird results (for example if the input string is broken into multiple strings).

   The matching happens on the tokens, so what you've input is almost (lowercasing still works) matched directly against the prefix / postfix of the tokens in the index. Generally you'd want to avoid wildcard queries for general search queries, since they're rather limited for natural search and can give weird results (as shown).
2. Fuzzy search [is based on "edit distance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - i.e. a number that tells Solr how many characters can be removed/inserted/changed to get to the resulting token. This will give your users OK-ish results, but might be hard to decipher in the sense of "why did this give me a hit" when the allowed distance is larger (Lucene/Solr supports up to 2 in edit distance which is also the default if no edit distance is given).
3. Stemming is usually the way to go, as it's the actual "formal" process of taking a term and reducing it down to its stem - the actual "meaning" (it doesn't really know anything about the meaning as in the natural language processing term, but it does it according to a set of static rules and exceptions for the language configured) of the word . It can be adjusted per language to rules suitable for that language, which neither of the two other options can.

   For your downside regarding stemming ("Since it can't match pumps") - that might actually be a good thing. It'll be clearer to your users what the search results are based on, and instead of including `pumps` in your search result, include it as a spelling correction ("Did you mean `pump` / `pumps` instead?"). It'll give a far better experience for any user, where the search results will more closely match what they're searching for.

   The requirements might differ based on what your actual use case is; i.e. if it's just for programmatic attempts to find terms that look similar.

**Question 2**

Present those results you deem more relevant as the first hits - if you're doing wildcard or fuzzy searches you can't do this through scoring alone, so you'll have to make several queries and then present them after each other. I usually suggest making that an explicit action by the user of the search when discussing this in projects.

Instead, as the main search, you can use an NGramFilter in a separate field and use a copyfield instruction to get the same content into both fields - and then score the ngramfilter far lower than hits in the more "exact" field. Usually you want three fields in that case - one for exact hits (non-stemmed), one for stemmed hits and one for ngram hits - and then score them appropriately with the `qf` parameter to edismax. It usually gives you the quickest and easiest results to a decent search results for your users, but make sure to give them decent ways of either filtering the result set (facets) or change their queries into something more meaningful (did you mean, also see xyz, etc.).

Guessing the user's intent is usually very hard unless you have invested a lot of time and resources into personalisation (think Google), so leave that for later - most users are happy as long as they have a clear and distinct way of solving their own problems, even if you don't get it perfect for the first result.

Comment: an answer with all the details...much appreciated...+1

Answer (score 0):

For question 2 you can go strict to permissive.

Option one: Only give strict search result. If no result found give stemmer results. Continue with fuzzy or wildcard search if no result found previously.

Option two: Give all results but rank them by level (ie. first exact match, then stemmer result, ...)